# Template for directive must have exactly one root element because of installing xray

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angularjs-directive, coffeescript

I used `JST` to call the template of directive. And It was working well.

This's example of one directive `navbar`:

```
App.directive 'navbar', [ '$compile', '$location', 'Tab', ($compile, $location, Tab)->
 behaviour =
  restrict: 'A'
  replace: true
  template: JST['navbar']()
  link: (scope, elem, attrs)->
```

Then I tried to install [xray-rails](https://github.com/brentd/xray-rails). And I run the following command:

```
bundle && rm -rf tmp/cache/assets
```

After that I got the following error without any change in the code:

```
Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'navbar' must have exactly one root element.
```

However, The root path is defined in `application.rb` file as the following:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'vendor', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

1. How can I fix this error ?
2. Did the command of `rm -rf tmp/cache/assets` make any effect for the root path of all templates for `JST` call ?

Comment: means you don't have one element wrapping the rest of the template, has nothing to do with path

Comment: basically wrap you whole template elements in a div

Comment: @charlietfl Excuse me, Can you explain with more details ? How can have element wrapping the rest of template ?

Comment: @apneadiving you said as Charlietfl ... But I don't know How wrap the template ? ... And why this error is occurred after remove the cache folder ?

Comment: in your html template, add `<div>` at the very beginning and `</div>` at the end

Comment: Actually I have already wrap the template in one div ... I solved the issue by uninstall `xray` & remove the tmp folder `rm -rf tmp/` .. the page is working well 
Do you know how to fix the conflict of `xray` gem ?